# Difference in calculations on Samsung Android vs Apple vs Google vs my own

Tags: arithmetic, math-software

While scripting a simple calculator in Javascript I came across this issue while checking my output with output from other calculators

500/5*2/50%2

Samsung = 800
Apple = 100
Google Calc = 800
My calculator = 0.08

My calculator above executes from left to right as all operators have same precedence. But which one is actual correct answere?

Comment: This is just a matter of order of operations. There is no correct answer

Comment: What does the % operation mean?  When I put this expression into Google calc I got $0$

Comment: What does this have to do with operator algebras? Also, $500/5*2/50\%2$ is the most ambiguous thing I've ever seen.

Comment: @Azif00 please elaborate?

Comment: @Gae.S.do you mean parenthesis? How does that come into play in this operation?

Comment: Of course the parenthesis are very important here. The operations $/$ and $\%$ are not associative.

Comment: No. I mean that $0$ is my first guess, and you claim that your calculator uses the same operation order I would.

Comment: What operation?  You use parentheses to indicate what the sequence of operations is.

Comment: @Gae.S. As I said above, [Google calc](https://www.google.com/search?q=500%2F5*2%2F50%252&oq=500%2F5*2%2F50%252&aqs=chrome..69i57.1841j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) gives $0$.

Comment: @saulspatz Ah, ok. I wasn't reading your comment.

Comment: @saulspatz But by adding ( ) you are modifying the question. Shouldn't the same input yield the same answere across any calculator?

Comment: @amars No, because the expression without parentheses doesn't have a well-defined meaning.  By adding parenthesis you are specifying a meaning, not changing the meaning.  Until you add the parentheses, it doesn't have a meaning.

Answer (score 0):

It surprises many non-mathematicians but there is no standards body setting the rules of mathematics.  So, there is often no official answer to questions such as this.  Chemistry has [IUPAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Union_of_Pure_and_Applied_Chemistry) so a similar question in Chemistry might have an official answer.  There is no similar body for mathematics.

There are some points that pretty much all serious mathematicians will agree on e.g. $2 + 3 \times 4 = 14$ rather than $20$.  Questions on the meaning of $a / b / c$ don't generally even come up since it would be rare to write that.

% as an operator is just a feature of some programming languages and not mathematics in general.  In some languages it may have no meaning and, even when it has a meaning, it may vary from language to language.  In your case, I suspect that % is being interpreted quite differently in each case.  How do you expect it to be interpreted?  I cannot guess what you want.

A particular language will have its rules and hence it may be possible to say what is the correct answer for that language.  However, even the language's rules may not cover all cases and it might come down to chance behaviour of the compiler or interpreter.